# Update an "Order" column after deleting a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a `ProductsImages` table which includes `ImageId, Productid ,Order` :

```
ProductId   ImageId    Order
----------------------------
    1          1        1
    1          2        2
    1          3        3
    1          4        4
    1          5        5
```

When I delete a row, let's say `ProductId = 1` `ImageId = 1` I need to update the order column :

```
ProductId   ImageId    Order
----------------------------
    1          2        1
    1          3        2
    1          4        3
    1          5        4
```

Comment: Why do you need to update the column? It will still be in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do the `delete`, you can do an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select pi.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productId order by [order]) as neworder
      from ProductImages pi
     )
update toupdate
    set [order] = neworder;
```

The above updates the whole table.  If you just want to update the changed product, add a `where` clause:

```
with toupdate as (
      select pi.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productId order by [order]) as neworder
      from ProductImages pi
      where pi.ProductID = @ProductId
     )
update toupdate
    set [order] = neworder;
```